# Swagger UI : "Choose file" button when input has both file AND json object?

Tags: asp.net, swagger-ui

*Asp.Net, .Net 5.0*

I have this `POST` endpoint that requires to BOTH upload a **file** and a "complex" object (**json**). In order to test it, I use **Swagger UI**.

**1. Testing the upload of a file alone is easy.**

If the endpoint looks like this...

```
public ActionResult TestUpload(bool testBool, IFormFile file) {
```

...then Swagger UI looks like this :

[image]

**2. Testing the upload of a json object alone is easy too.**

```
public class DummyInput {
    public bool Field { get; set; }
}
```

If the endpoint looks like this...

```
public ActionResult TestUpload(bool testBool, DummyInput input) {
```

...then Swagger UI looks like this :

[image]

**3. I can even make my life easier like this :**

public ActionResult TestUpload(bool testBool, **[FromForm]** DummyInput input) {

[image]

That's great.

**4. But what if I want BOTH the file and the 'input' json object ?**

**attempt #1 :**

```
public ActionResult TestUpload(bool testBool, IFormFile file, DummyInput input) {
```

That obviously doesn't work because you cannot have two parameters "From body", there can be only one.

**attempt #2:**

public ActionResult TestUpload(bool testBool, **[FromForm]** IFormFile file, **[FromForm]**
DummyInput input) {

[image]

**attempt #3:**

```
public class WrapperInput {
    public DummyInput Input { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}


public ActionResult TestUpload(bool testBool, WrapperInput input) {
```

[image]

So, in conclusion :  how do I get to enter my nice fields AND my "Select file" button?
I've looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058838/swagger-listing-iformfile-parameter-as-type-object) but it seems overly complicated -- and to be honest I'm not sure it's even related to my needs. I have a feeling that it's for OpenApi 2.0 rather than the better things we get from OpenApi 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

I found the right combination of settings, I was so close :

```
public class WrapperInput {
    public DummyInput Input { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

> public ActionResult TestUpload(bool testBool, **[FromForm]**
> WrapperInput input) {

Then you get this (image below). Solved!

[image]