# Swagger UI Json and Files at the same time

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I need your help.
No way with Swagger UI to have a json and a file in a request body.

I had a look at this post.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71046892/11648964)

The solution in the last comment is working fine but I have a json under a **form** format and the choose file button.
But I would like to have the json under a **body** format and also the file button.

Something like that:

[image: WhatIwant]

Like that I can just copy paste the json needed to modify the file via my API for example.

I am using :

```
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="6.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="6.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="6.5.0" />
```

Thanks for your help.

Concaho

I tried to do also a new RequestMixContentFilter which contains "application/json" and a "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" in a dictionary.
But in Swagger, I can select one or the other but I don't have both at the same time:
[image: Choicebetweenboth]

Answer (score 0):

OpenAPI doesn't support a way to describe the usage of `multipart/mixed` which is what you need here. That means SwaggerUI also doesn't support what you are trying to do.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: a title
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /v1/api:
    post:
      requestBody:
        description: a request for my api
        content:
          multipart/mixed:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy !
ok so how to handle this ? Create 2 post requests. One for a json and one for a file ? Or one post request but to use with Postman and not Swagger right ?

Comment: Only way to do it is create one post request and set the requestbody schema to `type: string, format: binary`